# How to use remote JMX connection in Websphere Application server 7.0

Tags: websphere, jmx, visualvm

I have a websphere application server environment running on a remote linux machine, with multiple appserver instances running. I want to use a tool like jconsole or visualvm on my local desktop to monitor the heap size of the individual appservers, but have no idea how to do it. The solutions found after googling do not tell how to enable multiple connections to individual appserver instances. Any help please ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable JMX connection for every app server instance. Once you did it, [add remote JMX connection](http://visualvm.java.net/jmx_connections.html) to those servers in VisualVM.